# move_base generating path in unknown space

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, dwa-local-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use ROS navigation stack with RPlidar A2.
currently, I am running `gmapping` with `move_base` and `explore_lite` so that robot can do auto-exploration and do SLAM.
the problem is, even though I set `allow_unkown` to false in dwa_local_planner_params.yaml, the path generated by move_base is going through the unknown space (I also checked the value being false with rosparam get)
Thank you for your help!

This is my costmap_common_parmas.yaml

```
obstacle_range: 2.5 #maximum obstale size
raytrace_range: 3.0 #robot will clear out space up to 3 meters 
footprint: [[-0.30,-0.177], [0.105,-0.177], [0.105, 0.177], [-0.30,0.177]] #not sure, from legacy
robot_radius: 0.2
inflation_radius: 0.3 #0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor 

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

This is my global_costmap.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
```

This is my local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom # NEW!! odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true # will remain centered around the robot as the robot moves around
  width: 5.0 #meters
  height: 5.0
  resolution: 0.01 #tend to set them equally as the static map
  static_map: true #if we use map_sever, keep it true
```

and I am using dwa_local_planner and A* for global_planner.

**EDIT**

After accepting the answer, I worked on properly setting the costmap yaml files and now it works properly. I have played with 'track_unkown_space' param and I decided to set them like these.
These are the files I have written.

common_costmap.yaml

```
obstacle_range: 2.5 #maximum obstale size
raytrace_range: 3.0 #robot will clear out space up to 3 meters 
footprint: [[-0.30,-0.177], [0.105,-0.177], [0.105, 0.177], [-0.30,0.177]] #not sure, from legacy
robot_radius: 0.2
inflation_radius: 0.3 #0.55
```

global_costmap.yaml (here, I set 'track_unkown_space' to true, since I wanted A* planner to only plan in known & free space) - make sure you load these in move_base.xml file with namespace global_costmap.

```
global_frame: map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 3.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
static_map: true #if we use map_sever, keep it true
  
  # obstacle_layer: {enabled: true, lethal_cost_threshold: 100, track_unknown_space: true, unknown_cost_value: -1}

  # static_layer: {enabled: true, lethal_cost_threshold: 100, track_unknown_space: true, unknown_cost_value: -1} 

plugins:
- {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"} 
- {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
- {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

static_layer:
  unknown_cost_value: 0 # default: 0
  lethal_cost_threshold: 100 # default: 100
  map_topic: map # default: "map"

obstacle_layer:
  combination_method: 1 #default 1, meaning we will combine the layers
  observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
  track_unknown_space: true
  map_type: costmap
  laser_scan_sensor:
    sensor_frame: laser_frame                 # default: ""
    topic: scan               # or /scan?
    data_type: LaserScan                # default: "PointCloud"
    marking: true                       # default: true
    clearing: true                      # default: false

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 0.45 # default: 0.55
```

local_costmap.yaml (here, I set 'track_unknown_space' to false, since DWA planner works fine with this param being  false.) I got this idea from this [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/364176/dwa-planner-failed-to-produce-path/)

```
global_frame: map # NEW!! odom
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: true # will remain centered around the robot as the robot moves around
width: 5.0 #meters
height: 5.0
resolution: 0.01 #tend to set them equally as the static map

plugins: 
- {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
- {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

obstacle_layer:
  combination_method: 1
  observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
  track_unknown_space: false
  map_type: costmap
  laser_scan_sensor:
    sensor_frame: laser_frame                 # default: ""
    topic: scan               # or /scan?
    data_type: LaserScan                # default: "PointCloud"
    marking: true                       # default: true
    clearing: true                      # default: false

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 0.45 # default: 0.55
```

**EDIT 2**
I just wanted to say that explore_lite won't work with this setting as explore_lite sets unkown area as goals. If I set the allow_unkown  to true, so that I could use explore_lite, the path generated wasn't appropriate as you can see in the picture.  However, the above setting with costmap layers works great with general navigation stack when given goals in know & free space, so I am trying to find exploration method that works with only known&free move_base goal.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369415/move_base-generating-path-in-unknown-space/) by [So Young](https://answers.ros.org/users/67634/so-young/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2021-01-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [So Young](https://answers.ros.org/users/67634/so-young/) on 2021-01-12**:
I've seen some posts about setting `track_unknown_space` to true, but since my costmap doesn't have layers, I thought wouldn't need to worry about that parameter. (or maybe I'm understanding it wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you may have seen, the documentation for `global_planner` states:

> `~<name>/allow_unknown` (`bool`, default: `true`)
>     Specifies whether or not to allow the planner to create plans that traverse unknown space. NOTE: if you are using a layered `costmap_2d` costmap with a voxel or obstacle layer, you must also set the `track_unknown_space` param for that layer to be `true`, or it will convert all your unknown space to free space (which planner will then happily go right through)

What you may have missed is that your cost map does contain layers, even when defined with pre-Hydro parameters.  From the [`costmap_2d` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d?distro=kinetic#costmap_2d.2Flayered.Pre-Hydro_Parameters):

> Pre-Hydro Parameters
>
> Hydro and later releases use plugins for all `costmap_2d` layers. If you don't provide a `plugins` parameter then the initialization code will assume that your configuration is pre-Hydro and will load a default set of plugins with default namespaces. Your parameters will be moved to the new namespaces automagically. The default namespaces are `static_layer`, `obstacle_layer` and `inflation_layer`. Some tutorials (and books) still refer to pre-Hydro parameters, so pay close attention. To be safe, be sure to provide a `plugins` parameter.

Therefore, it seems you'll still need to set `track_unknown_space` to `true` in the `obstacle_layer` namespace.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [So Young](https://answers.ros.org/users/67634/so-young/) on 2021-01-13**:
Thank you, yes I didn't know my costmap had default layers. I'll try to set them properly and also set `track_unkown_space` and see if it works!

**Comment by [So Young](https://answers.ros.org/users/67634/so-young/) on 2021-01-13**:
Thank you for helping me with this problem, I have fixed the costmap yamls and  now it works properly. I have also edited my post. Thanks!